# pulseaudio noise cancellation for a different device

Tags: pulseaudio

I  have a microphone (jack input) that picks up a bit of hiss. I use it with an old web cam to teach lessons and record lessons. I added "load-module module-echo-cancel" to /etc/pulse/default.pa and that has been a brilliant help cleaning up the audio. I have two options,

mic
mic with noise cancellation

However, I upgraded my webcam to a slightly less cheap one. It has a built in mic. The problem is now I have three options;

the original mic (without noise cancellation),
the new webcam
the new webcam with noise cancellation.

I want to use the old mic for the lessons but I need it with noise cancellation. How do I get that back while keeping the new usb webcam plugged in as i need that?

Comment: I think I solved it. Started up pavucontrol.  Then I went to 'recording' then show all streams.  I was able to change the input source for the echo cancel module there.

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum.